# Parse Error: Line 9: Unexpected identifier in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is error in this, i am simply following the new boston tutorial and while doing this i don't know why this error is coming

I edited the code now, it still not working

Code:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>React Practice</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/jsx">
             class Basics extends React.Component {
            constructor () {
                super();
                this.state = {checked: true}
            }
            render(this.state.checked) {
                var msg;
                if () {
                    msg = 'checked';
                } else {
                    msg = 'unchecked';
                }
                return (
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <h2>Checkbox is {msg}</h2>
                    </div>
                ) 
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(<Basics />, document.getElementById('example'));
        </script>  
        <div id="example"></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite weird for me, I would write it as follows:

```
            getInitialState() {
                return {checked:true}
            }
            render() {
                var msg;
                if (this.state.checked) {
                    msg = 'checked';
                } else {
                    msg = 'unchecked';
                }
                return (
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <h2>Checkbox is {msg}</h2>
                    </div>
                ) 
            }
        }
```

You had empty `if()`, and `render()` should not take any params, I don't know why you use `msg: checked` instead of `msg = 'checked'` (maybe some JS transpiler which I didn't see before). I would also move initial state to constructor:

```
constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {checked: true}
}
```

and remove `getInitialState()` method. Outside constructor, you should always use `setState()` method.
And, as you pointed out in comments section, you should not use comma after method declaration, it is needed in object declaration but forbidden in ES 6 class declaration.

Comment: It's not working... i replaced it with constructor but the error always comes at render()... i guess it something related to comma... not sure.

Comment: @naveendharni Of course :) You should not have comma here, this is not Object but class declaration :) By the way, my comments also can be applied to this code.

Comment: After removing the comma it still not working, wait i edit my code.

Comment: @naveendharni Now move `this.state.checked` from `render()` declaration to `empty if()`. It should look like this: `render()` and `if (this.state.checked)`.

Comment: Oh okay i don't know why i put condition in render. so i have some questions regarding this.what is use of constructor here or for any react app why can't i use it as getInitial() as it taught in video tutorial.

Comment: @naveendharni Is it working now? So, you should use `getInitialState` when using ES 5 `React.createClass` and `constructor` when you use ES 6 `class` syntax. Maybe you can combine them, but it makes a mess in code and it may cause problem when code is transpiled if you use Babel for older browsers.

Comment: Can i ask you few more things from this question, i am really new to react and want to learn it.

Comment: What is the use of constructor?how to understand that why should i use it or not?

Comment: @naveendharni If you use `class Something extends Something` constructor is required, you should also call parent constructor `super()`. In general, you always need `constructor` for initial values (it is run to create an instance of class), not only for React but also for Javascript at all. It could be useful for you to read about ES 6 class syntax, because before ES 6 Javascript does not have classes.

Comment: So if i want to create a new variable i need to write it in constructor?

Comment: @naveendharni No, you need constructor only for classes. Variables in functions does not need to be inside constructor (like `msg` in `render`) but if you want to create property (visible in all class methods) it's good practise to initiate it inside constructor (like `this.service = new Service()` and you have instance available to all methods).

Comment: Okay i think i need to learn a lot do you any tutorial which is in ES6 because i'm watching it in ES5 but have to use ES6 and it becomes such a great mess

Comment: IN ES5 when you create  new function you seperate it with comma but this doesn't happen in ES6.

Comment: @naveendharni It is a good idea. ES 6 brings new things to Javascript standard which makes development much easier, but it may took some time to learn it. I wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks for helping